# How to have node and django running under one SSL server?

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, port, uwsgi

is there a way to solve this:
there is a domain example.com, on port 80 it redirects to 443 so it's always SSL connection and it passes to uwsgi via nginx. Now sockets run via a node connection on example.com:3000.

Is there an  easy way to have that example.com:3000 run as SSL? The reason why is that Chrome gives a warning that the site includes resources that are not SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another server in nginx, with the same domain listener but for different ports and passed the info through to node, and made that port SSL.